# Script 'S2Quickstart' not found When adding Spring security plugin

Tags: grails

I typed the following commands to add the `Spring security plugin`.

```
$ grails install-plugin spring-security-core

$ grails s2-quickstart org.example.auth Person Authority
```

When i type the above command all what i get is:

```
| Script 'S2Quickstart' not found, did you mean:
   1) Stats
   2) DbmListLocks
   3) InstallJQuery
   4) TestApp
   5) DbmClearChecksums
> Please make a selection or enter Q to quit: q
```

How can i solve this ?

UPDATE

```
| Configuring classpath
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.0.RC1, org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.0.RC1: Could not find artifact org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.0.RC1 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.0.RC1, org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.0.RC1: Could not find artifact org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.0.RC1 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.0.RC1, org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.0.RC1: Could not find artifact org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.0.RC1 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.0.RC1, org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.0.RC1: Could not find artifact org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.0.RC1 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins)
| Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.
```

Comment: I have the same problem with grails 2.3.6 after following the exact steps in the official documentation (which matches what Hussian says).  No solution found.

Comment: Assuming s2-quickstart is not working in 2.3.6, how can what it does be manually created?  Could someone list the files it generates/modifies?

Answer (score 10):

since you're using 2.3.4
install-plugin is deprecated

here is what you do

step 1 : open BuilConfig.groovy

step 2 : add this line in repositories

```
mavenRepo "http://repo.spring.io/milestone/"

repositories {
        mavenRepo "http://repo.spring.io/milestone/"
    }
```

step 3 : add this line in plugins snippet

```
compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC2"

plugins {
    compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC2'
}
```

step 4 : execute command

```
grails compile
```

step 5 : execute command

```
s2-quickstart
```

and you're done

Comment: this did not fix it for me using grails 2.3.6

Comment: are you getting any special , error , warning message ??

Comment: I found my partiular issue, I had this: compile: ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC2" which has an extra : in it.  this produced no warnings or errors.  Removing the extra : fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

After running

```
grails install-plugin spring-security-core
```

you need to compile the app first. By running

```
grails compile
```

Then, you run

```
grails s2-quickstart org.example.auth Person Authority
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't say which version of Grails, but assuming 2.0+, don't use `install-plugin` (it's deprecated), instead, follow the [plugin install instructions](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) and

> Add the following to your grails-app/conf/BuildConfig
>
> ```
>     plugins {
>         compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC2'
>     }
> ```

Then run `grails compile`, and the `s2-quickstart` task will be available

Comment: I have updated my post, i get the another error after adding the line you suggested

Comment: Its Grails version: 2.3.4

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Add this to the plugins

```
    plugins {
        compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC2'
    }
```

And then add this to the repositories

```
    repositories {        
        mavenRepo 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone'
    }
```

Then do a clean and compile, and then run

```
    grails s2-quickstart org.example.auth Person Authority
```